# Add icon to the node depending on the value of the cell of another column. DevExpress Tree List ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress, devexpress-mvc, devexpress-gridcontrol

I am working with TreeList in ASP.NET MVC using DevExpress. Currently the code I have works, but it only adds the same icon on all nodes I would like to add a different icon depending on the `Tag` column / cell value.

For example if the `Tag` column has the value `Visit Summary`, I would like to add in the node an icon related to it.

I leave this image with my tree list and the code below.

[image]

```
settings.Columns.Add("Description").SetDataCellTemplateContent(c =>
{
    Html.DevExpress().Image(image =>
    {
        image.Name = "image" + c.NodeKey;
        image.Properties.EmptyImage.IconID = IconID.BusinessobjectsBoFolderSvg16x16;
    }).GetHtml();

    Html.DevExpress().Label(label =>
    {
        label.Name = "Label" + c.NodeKey;
        object value = DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, c.Column.FieldName);
        if (value != null)
            label.Text = value.ToString() + "    ";
    }).GetHtml();
});
```